# use sql LIKE to match full words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to search for entire word not part of them

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '% $q %'
```

for example if `$q = mag` it shouldn't find magazine
i've tried solutions that users posted but it didn't work

like REGEX and CONCAT

ps: my db column is a big text

Comment: MATCH() only works on myiasm database type though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whether this will solve your issue or you have already tried but give it a try and
  look for word boundaries with the following `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column  RLIKE "[[:<:]]$q[[:>:]]";
```

Comment: it returns nothing in my query

Comment: can you do one thing. can you print the query and run directly in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LIKE`...Use only comparison in this case. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$q';
```

Comment: No, OP want that `"Foo barbaz baz"` will be found for `"baz"`, but not `"bar"`, so it isn't equality

Comment: But user says that when `$q='mag'` then fetch row containing `mag` and not `magazine`. This simple query will give output as `magazine` only. @AlmaDo.. may be I misunderstood...not sure

Comment: `$q` i get it from url the user has to write whole word in textfield not part of it @Butterfruit

Answer (score 0):

If your words are separated by spaces, then add spaces on both sides:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE concat(' ', column, ' ') LIKE '% $q %';
```